# Xcode 11 - issues to get new simulators

Tags: xcode

After upgrading to Xcode 11, I tried to add a iPhone Xs or Xr simulator but after creating it under "Devices and Simulators" it doesn't appear. How to get it on the list?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is a known issue

[Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes)

Check RN:

> Bundles without a CFBundleVersion are invalid and can’t be properly installed on devices or simulators. CoreSimulator now checks and rejects such bundles earlier in the process with a clearer error message. (49892531)

Hence you should try with this procedure:

- Uninstall Code
- Install XCode 10
- Remove /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework
- Again XCode 10.x launch and agree to install command line tools

Comment: Ok thanks, but does it means it works for you with this XCode 11 version?